# How to disable AUTO SUGGESTION in a Textfield in Flutter and other problems with KEYBOARDTYPE in IOS

Tags: flutter, keyboard, flutter-textformfield

Am working on a vocabulary learning app (from English to French and vice versa).
When doing quizzes, I would prefer it if user didn't have suggestions on the suggestion bar (as it helps with spelling).
I tried disabling options in the textfield, but nothing works.
Here is the code :

```
Container(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: TextFormField(
              smartQuotesType: SmartQuotesType.disabled,
              autofocus: true,
              enableSuggestions: false,
              autocorrect: false,
              controller: fieldText,
              
              keyboardType:
                  TextInputType.visiblePassword,
              enabled: pasfini,
              enableInteractiveSelection: false,
              autovalidateMode:
                  AutovalidateMode.disabled,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Ecris la traduction'),
              onChanged: (value) {
                word = value;
              },
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  exoEnCours = true;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
```

The only thing that seems to work is if I set keyboardType to email address... But in that case the space bar becomes very small and the @ sign appears...

I don't understand why the enableSuggestions : false and autocorrect : false do not work. It is specified in the API documentation that for IOS : AUTOCORRECT should be set to false for this to be disabled.

Do you know if there's a flutter bug ?

I tried to debug the same code on an ANDROID DEVICE, and it worked fine. There seems to be a problem with IOS....

I have the same problem with another option of the TEXTFIELD widget : the one linked with CAPITALIZATION.

```
TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: uD.device == Device.smallMobile
                            ? uD.smallFont2
                            : uD.mediumFont2),
                    initialValue: name,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                    autocorrect: false,
                    enableSuggestions: false,
                    decoration: kTextFormFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                      labelText: 'Nom du responsable légal',
                    ),
```

It never capitalizes the first letter of the fieldText. It works fine on Android.

Comment: Are you testing on real device or simulator? Android or IOS ?

Comment: Am testing on a real device - iPhone Xmax Pro

Comment: Tried the code on an Android device and it works fine. How can we report this problem to flutter team ?

Comment: Try keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword

Comment: It is mentioned here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22828

Comment: Yes I am using "keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword" in my code. I think I found another problem : textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words, doesn't work either on IOS.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue you had and the solution was to use the Cupertino text field type. You can implement it by first importing it the package
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

Then you use the TextInputType.name instead of TextInputType.emailAddress
This will work perfectly disabling the autosuggestions. Include it with the other factors properties that disable suggestions below:

autocorrect: false,
enableSuggestions: false,
enableIMEPersonalizedLearning: false,
TextInputType.name,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).